# Navigation drop down to remain for a few seconds after mouse off

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to achieve a similar result with the drop down menu like http://www.saota.com/ on my site http://creativepreview.co.za/noero. I can't figure out what css to use on the hover state to achieve this.
I've tried

```
#top-menu li li:hover{
    transition: 3s ease;
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Just use `#top-menu li li{transition:3s ease;}` remove the `:hover`

Comment: You will need to use javascript for this. CSS will lose hover state once you move your mouse away from the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you hide/show the submenu using `visibility` . Transition DOES NOT work with non-numeric values like `visibility:visible/hidden` or `display:none/block` . you should try to hide/show it only with `opacity` or other transitional styles.

also i saw that you have some classes added to li on hover. add/remove class with javascript is also NOT transitional. So be careful to have a code that suits your purpose.

see example below

P.S. next time, post your code here and make an example of you problem, do not link to external website. Your question could be closed/deleted

```css
ul.first ul {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 3s;
}

ul.first li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

ul.second ul {
  visibility: hidden;

  transition: 3s;
}

ul.second li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;

}
```

```html
<ul class="first">
<li>Hover Me OPACITY
 <ul>
 <li>ooo</li>
 <li>aaaa</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
<li>Hover Me VISIBLITY
 <ul>
 <li>ooo</li>
 <li>aaaa</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Transition to both.

## top-menu li li{transition: all 3s ease;}

## top-menu li li:hover{transition: all 3s ease;}

Comment: No it still jumps away when you mouse off - any other suggestions? http://creativepreview.co.za/noero.